# How to set seekbar value which user already selected

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Hello can anyone help me 
how to set seek bar value 
by default, its min value is 0 and max value is 1000

now if user set min value 20 and max value 400 
and apply the filter
again user need to change filter value from 20 to 30 and 400 to 450
but in my case filter range, seek bar value  is again starting from 0 to 1000

how to set which user-selected value.
please find attachment [![First default filter][1]][1]
[![Second Filter which user-selected values ][2]][2]
Here is my code.

```
final RangeSeekBar rangeSeekbar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekBar);
       rangeSeekbar.setMinThumbValue(prefs.getInt("minValue", 10));
                rangeSeekbar.setMaxThumbValue(prefs.getInt("maxValue", 10000));
 rangeSeekbar.setSeekBarChangeListener(new
                                                              RangeSeekBar.SeekBarChangeListener() {
                                                                  @Override
                                                                  public void onStartedSeeking() {

                                                                  }

                                                                  @Override
                                                                  public void onStoppedSeeking() {
                                                                      editor.putInt("minValue", rangeSeekbar.getMinThumbValue());
                                                                      editor.putInt("maxValue", rangeSeekbar.getMaxThumbValue());
                                                                      editor.apply();
                                                                  }

                                                                  @Override
                                                                  public void onValueChanged(int i, int i1) {
                                                                      price_min.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                                                                      price_max.setText(String.valueOf(i1));
                                                                  }
                                                              });
```

xml CODE

```
 <com.innovattic.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/rangeSeekBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:rsb_maxThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_circle"
                        app:rsb_maxThumbOffsetHorizontal="2dp"
                        app:rsb_minRange="10"
                        app:rsb_max="10000"
                        app:rsb_minThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_circle"
                        app:rsb_minThumbOffsetHorizontal="-2dp"
                        app:rsb_trackColor="#888"
                        app:rsb_trackSelectedColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        app:rsb_trackSelectedThickness="4dp"
                        app:rsb_trackThickness="2dp" />
```

for checkbox code,
 it's working fine but I need if already selected checkbox set checked true

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(datum.isSelected());
            holder.checkbox.setTag(moviesList.get(position));

            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String data = "";
                    ResultGetCategory fruits1 = (ResultGetCategory)holder.checkbox.getTag();

                    fruits1.setSelected(holder.checkbox.isChecked());

                    moviesList.get(position).setSelected(holder.checkbox.isChecked());

                    for (int j=0; j<moviesList.size();j++){

                        if (moviesList.get(j).isSelected() == true){
                            data = data + "\n" + moviesList.get(j).getName().toString();
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selected Fruits : \n " + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: your problem goes to text views, update them before listener

Comment: ok let me check again

can you help me one more
how to use multiple checkboxes in recycler view 
for  example there are 10 values in array 
and user need to check 4 item from them 
again if user come to checkbox filter that 4 item already set check true and if he want to add more or remove from it

Comment: Updated code for check box

please help me so I can finished my work

Comment: i am here and i will help you but we must talk about it in another question bcz of community .share new question link here with me

Comment: sry but unable to ask new question thats why i updated code pls look it on

Comment: i cant realise what is your problem

Comment: problem is same as flipkart filter 
price range checkbox if once check and apply filter and come back to change range than old checkbox is selected 

same here i also want 
but its reseting all check box not save ing

Comment: ok, you can do it with prefs.putBoolean  and get it just like what we did in values

Comment: i tried but now succes app crash so pls add this code also in post please dear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510385/how-to-set-check-box-true-if-once-checked-in-recycler-view-like-flipkart-price-r

iasked as new post pls check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save your values in sharedpreferences and set them if not null in your seekbar when created by class like this:

```
range_seek_bar.setMin(*/value from sharedprefs/*);
range_seek_bar.setMax(*/value from sharedprefs/*);
```

Notice :

each Library of range seekbars had deferent methods and maybe upper code is not suite for you, it's just a sample that show you the way.

Update:

the total code for this library:

```
  import com.innovattic.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar;
```

take care of imports:

```
    RangeSeekBar rangeSeekbar;
    rangeSeekbar = findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekbar2);
    //Context context;
    SharedPreferences prefs = 
         this.getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();



    rangeSeekbar.setMinThumbValue(prefs.getInt("minValue",1));
    rangeSeekbar.setMaxThumbValue(prefs.getInt("maxValue",100));

    rangeSeekbar.setSeekBarChangeListener(new 
            RangeSeekBar.SeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartedSeeking() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStoppedSeeking() {
            editor.putInt("minValue",rangeSeekbar.getMinThumbValue());
            editor.putInt("maxValue",rangeSeekbar.getMaxThumbValue());
            editor.apply();
        }

        @Override
        public void onValueChanged(int i, int i1) {
            //price_min.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            //price_max.setText(String.valueOf(i1));
        }
    });
```

this is link for library that i used and worked:
[Library for range bar](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7063)

for more help:

```
    <com.innovattic.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:rsb_minRange="0"
    app:rsb_max="400"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: Can you write code for me  Sry but I am new in this please dear help eme

Comment: waiting for your updated code dear
and if you suggest any other seekbar so I can use it for easy way but need 2 thumb

Comment: updated and i test it, don't forget to change class of xml file

Comment: Yes its working now but one issue is there 
price won't save its start from 0 again

Comment: min value in this library started at 1 not 0.

Comment: ya in my case min price is 10 and max price is 10000

Comment: but it is still again starting from 10 ]

Comment: Are you there dear can you help me in updated question

Answer (score 0):

this answer for your second question :

```
       checkBox.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean("checkbox",false));
       checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
                 CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean 
                                    isChecked) {
            //add your code here when set checked changed
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox",isChecked);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but it is not working, If I select 1 checkbox and apply after come back all checkbox are selected