# How to set check box true if once checked in RecyclerView like flipkart price range

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

Hello can any one help me how to set checked true checkbox in RecyclerView if user checked it once and apply filter same as flipkart price filter

here is my code :-

```
    final ResultGetCategory datum = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.label_category_name.setText(datum.getName());
    //checkbox click event handling

    holder.checkbox.setChecked(datum.isSelected());
    holder.checkbox.setTag(moviesList.get(position));

    SharedPreferences prefsCheckBox = getContext().getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(holder.checkbox.getTag()), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editorCheckbox = prefsCheckBox.edit();

    holder.checkbox.setTag(moviesList.get(position));
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(
            prefsCheckBox.getBoolean(String.valueOf(holder.checkbox.getTag()), false));
    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new
                                                       CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                                           @Override
                                                           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                                                        boolean isChecked) {
                                                               //add your code here when set checked changed


                                                               editorCheckbox.putBoolean(String.valueOf(holder.checkbox.getTag()),isChecked);
                                                               editorCheckbox.apply();
                                                           }
                                                       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it instead of set on click:

```
    holder.checkbox.setTag(moviesList.get(position));
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(
           prefs.getBoolean(
              String.valueOf(holder.checkbox.getTag(),false));
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
         CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                     boolean isChecked) {
            //add your code here when set checked changed
            editor.putBoolean(
                String.valueOf(holder.checkbox.getTag()),isChecked);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

this code work for multiple checkboxes in a ListView
each checkbox have a sharedpreferences boolean value and all default is false.

Your Updated code:

```
    final ResultGetCategory datum = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.label_category_name.setText(datum.getName());
    //checkbox click event handling

    holder.checkbox.setChecked(datum.isSelected());
    holder.checkbox.setTag(moviesList.get(position));
/*
  //move commented lines to viewholder class or in constructor of 
      adapter
  //exactly these codes and dont change them
    SharedPreferences prefsCheckBox = 
       getContext().getSharedPreferences("checkbox", 
           Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editorCheckbox = prefsCheckBox.edit();
*/
holder.checkbox.setTag(moviesList.get(position));
holder.checkbox.setChecked(

prefsCheckBox.getBoolean(
        String.valueOf(holder.checkbox.getTag()), false));
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new                                                    
          CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,                                                                                   
                                     boolean isChecked) {
  //add your code here when set checked changed



   editorCheckbox.putBoolean(
      String.valueOf(holder.checkbox.getTag()),isChecked);

        editorCheckbox.apply();
        }
 });
```

before test this code erase your app from device and install it again
Don't forget to change location of prefs initializing because it will happen for every cell and its not true.

Comment: Sorry for late reply

Comment: but its not working I select 1 checkbox and apply when come back all checkbox selected true

Comment: Because you must do it for each checkbox you have.
every check box must have a code like above .

Comment: I again updated my full code of adapter but still it is not working can you please update it again in my code please

Comment: ya let me check again

Comment: https://imgur.com/i09fbih

see an image I have checked 3 checkboxes in the adapter

Comment: https://imgur.com/undefined  
and again come back its rest all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205055/discussion-between-karan-israni-and-alireza-daryani).